# how to get database of all people's names (or at least English common ones)?

Tags: string

I'm designing an application that need to extract people's names from short texts.

What is the best way to do that? is there a database of names where I can test to know where is the name? the fact that the text is short it might not be as intensive in terms of processing needs.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Tam

Comment: Have you ever read A.C.Clarke's "9 Billion Names Of God"?  Consider the consequences if you ever got a complete list of names.

Comment: That's why astronomers keep counting stars...

Comment: @pavium Unless you are in Soviet Russia, Stars counting astronomers  xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a statistical [Named Entity Recognizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition) (NER), such as [Stanford's NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/ner/index.shtml), or [LingPipe's](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/ne/read-me.html). These are machine learning-based recognizers, that do not require huge dictionaries of names as input.

Alternatively, you can get a list of person names from the Web (there are plenty), and use the [Aho-Corasick string searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm) to efficiently extract names from the list from text.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a *nix system, try looking at `/usr/share/dict/propernames`. Mac OS X has it, and I think at least Ubuntu does too.

You could use this with `grep`:

```
grep -f /usr/share/dict/propernames short_text.txt
```

Comment: Ubuntu does not have the propernames by default, only english words, however you can probably add them. But yes, OSX has it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this reference: [Extracting people’s names from RSS feeds using WordNet](http://library.witpress.com/pages/PaperInfo.asp?PaperID=14219)

Comment: WordNet is great, but I'm afraid it will only be able to extract famous people's names, such as Washington.

Answer (score 2):

**Get A Name Dataset :** 
I have made a collection of datasets for tasks like that. You can use my datasets here : https://mbejda.github.io.  They are all in CSV format. The names are categorized by race and Gender.

**Named Entity Recognizer :** 
Look into OpenNLP or StanfordNLP for named entity recognizer and extraction.

Answer (score 1):

How about US census bureau [genealogy data](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/names_files.html)